# React-Native Linking text in Alert

Tags: javascript, react-native

I made an where where I Alert some information. However, I would like to add a Link in the Alert message (using Linking probably). Is there a way to do it?

Is it possible to link a message in an Alert?

Answer (score 1):

You can have buttons on alert and then in code call the linking framework.